# Error: lib/Dashboard.dart:118:33: Error: Getter not found: 'context'

Tags: flutter

Can anyone explain how to deal with the context in tabs, I am using different functions within tabs, I am facing some issue related to the context. I am using the bottom navigation bar and working on tabs, I write the function in the tabs containing the whole content in it, I wrote further functions inside the tabs when I want to navigate to the other page from the tabs it need to provide the context but I don't have the context inside the tabs, need the solution
Kindly see the error:
lib/Dashboard.dart:118:33: Error: Getter not found: 'context'.
context,
^^^^^^^

```
import 'package:bubble_bottom_bar/bubble_bottom_bar.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:hisaab/ExpenceDisplayPage.dart';

class Dashboard extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DashboardState createState() => _DashboardState();
}

class _DashboardState extends State<Dashboard> {
  static String usename = "Abdul Rehman";
  static DateTime now = new DateTime.now();
  int _currentIndex = 0;
  final tabs = [
    _dashboardTab(),
    Center(child: Text("Profile")),
  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      body: tabs[_currentIndex],
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          _addItem(context);
        },
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        backgroundColor: Colors.cyan,
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.endDocked,
      bottomNavigationBar: BubbleBottomBar(
        opacity: .2,
        currentIndex: _currentIndex,
        onTap: (index) {
          setState(() {
            _currentIndex = index;
          });
        },
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(16)),
        elevation: 8,
        fabLocation: BubbleBottomBarFabLocation.end, //new
        hasNotch: true, //new
        hasInk: true, //new, gives a cute ink effect
        inkColor: Colors.black12, //optional, uses theme color if not specified
        items: <BubbleBottomBarItem>[
          BubbleBottomBarItem(
              backgroundColor: Colors.red,
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.dashboard,
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
              activeIcon: Icon(
                Icons.dashboard,
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
              title: Text("Dashboard")),
          BubbleBottomBarItem(
              backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple,
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.person,
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
              activeIcon: Icon(
                Icons.person,
                color: Colors.deepPurple,
              ),
              title: Text("Profile")),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  static Container _dashboardTab() {
    return (Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          _userDetails(),
          _expenceContainers(),
          Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    topLeft: Radius.circular(60),
                    topRight: Radius.circular(60)),
                boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(
                      0.5,
                    ),
                    spreadRadius: 5,
                    blurRadius: 7,
                    offset: Offset(0, 2),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                    child: Text(
                      "Expence",
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: Colors.black),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    height: 400,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
                    child: ListView(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                          left: 16, right: 16, top: 30, bottom: 5),
                      children: [
                        Card(
                          child: ListTile(
                            onTap: () {
                              Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) => ExpenceDisplayPage()),
                              );
                            },
                            title: Text("Grocery Items"),
                            subtitle: Text("Household"),
                            trailing: Wrap(
                              children: [
                                Column(
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                                  children: [
                                    Text(
                                      "200",
                                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      '${now.day}' +
                                          '/${now.month}' +
                                          '/${now.year}',
                                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                            dense: true,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              )),
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }

  static Container _userDetails() {
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16, 30, 16, 0),
      height: 100,
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(1),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Color.fromRGBO(47, 79, 79, 1),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30)),
        boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(
            color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(
              0.5,
            ),
            spreadRadius: 5,
            blurRadius: 7,
            offset: Offset(0, 2),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(19),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(color: Colors.white),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30)),
        ),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            Container(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    "Welcome",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    usename,
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    '${now.day}' + '/${now.month}' + '/${now.year}',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    "Total Expence",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    "20678 Pkr",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  static _expenceContainers() {
    return (Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: [
          Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Color.fromRGBO(119, 136, 153, 1),
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(
                      0.5,
                    ),
                    spreadRadius: 5,
                    blurRadius: 7,
                    offset: Offset(0, 2),
                  ),
                ]),
            width: 100,
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(2),
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(18),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                border: Border.all(color: Colors.white),
              ),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Text(
                    "Today",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10, color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    "99 Pkr",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10, color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 128, 128, 1),
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(
                      0.5,
                    ),
                    spreadRadius: 5,
                    blurRadius: 7,
                    offset: Offset(0, 2),
                  ),
                ]),
            width: 100,
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(1),
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(18),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                border: Border.all(color: Colors.white),
              ),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Text(
                    "7 Days",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10, color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    "1560 Pkr",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10, color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Color.fromRGBO(128, 128, 0, 1),
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(
                      0.5,
                    ),
                    spreadRadius: 5,
                    blurRadius: 7,
                    offset: Offset(0, 2),
                  ),
                ]),
            width: 100,
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(1),
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(18),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                border: Border.all(color: Colors.white),
              ),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Text(
                    "30 Days",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10, color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    "25467 Pkr",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10, color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can init `tabs` in `initState` and pass `context` to `_dashboardTab`
code snippet

```
List<Widget> tabs;

@override
void initState() {
    tabs = [
      _dashboardTab(context),
      Center(child: Text("Profile")),
    ];
    super.initState();
  }
...  
static Container _dashboardTab(BuildContext context) {
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:bubble_bottom_bar/bubble_bottom_bar.dart';

class Dashboard extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DashboardState createState() => _DashboardState();
}

class _DashboardState extends State<Dashboard> {
  static String usename = "Abdul Rehman";
  static DateTime now = new DateTime.now();
  int _currentIndex = 0;
  List<Widget> tabs;

  @override
  void initState() {
    tabs = [
      _dashboardTab(context),
      Center(child: Text("Profile")),
    ];
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      body: tabs[_currentIndex],
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          //_addItem(context);
        },
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        backgroundColor: Colors.cyan,
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.endDocked,
      bottomNavigationBar: BubbleBottomBar(
        opacity: .2,
        currentIndex: _currentIndex,
        onTap: (index) {
          setState(() {
            _currentIndex = index;
          });
        },
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(16)),
        elevation: 8,
        fabLocation: BubbleBottomBarFabLocation.end, //new
        hasNotch: true, //new
        hasInk: true, //new, gives a cute ink effect
        inkColor: Colors.black12, //optional, uses theme color if not specified
        items: <BubbleBottomBarItem>[
          BubbleBottomBarItem(
              backgroundColor: Colors.red,
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.dashboard,
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
              activeIcon: Icon(
                Icons.dashboard,
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
              title: Text("Dashboard")),
          BubbleBottomBarItem(
              backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple,
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.person,
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
              activeIcon: Icon(
                Icons.person,
                color: Colors.deepPurple,
              ),
              title: Text("Profile")),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  static Container _dashboardTab(BuildContext context) {
    return (Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            _userDetails(),
            _expenceContainers(),
            Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      topLeft: Radius.circular(60),
                      topRight: Radius.circular(60)),
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                      color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(
                        0.5,
                      ),
                      spreadRadius: 5,
                      blurRadius: 7,
                      offset: Offset(0, 2),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                      child: Text(
                        "Expence",
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: Colors.black),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      height: 400,
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
                      child: ListView(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                            left: 16, right: 16, top: 30, bottom: 5),
                        children: [
                          Card(
                            child: ListTile(
                              onTap: () {
                                Navigator.push(
                                  context,
                                  MaterialPageRoute(
                                      builder: (context) =>
                                          ExpenceDisplayPage()),
                                );
                              },
                              title: Text("Grocery Items"),
                              subtitle: Text("Household"),
                              trailing: Wrap(
                                children: [
                                  Column(
                                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                                    children: [
                                      Text(
                                        "200",
                                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                                      ),
                                      Text(
                                        '${now.day}' +
                                            '/${now.month}' +
                                            '/${now.year}',
                                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                              dense: true,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                )),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ));
  }

  static Container _userDetails() {
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16, 30, 16, 0),
      height: 100,
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(1),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Color.fromRGBO(47, 79, 79, 1),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30)),
        boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(
            color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(
              0.5,
            ),
            spreadRadius: 5,
            blurRadius: 7,
            offset: Offset(0, 2),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(19),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(color: Colors.white),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30)),
        ),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            Container(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    "Welcome",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    usename,
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    '${now.day}' + '/${now.month}' + '/${now.year}',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    "Total Expence",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    "20678 Pkr",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  static _expenceContainers() {
    return (Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: [
          Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Color.fromRGBO(119, 136, 153, 1),
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(
                      0.5,
                    ),
                    spreadRadius: 5,
                    blurRadius: 7,
                    offset: Offset(0, 2),
                  ),
                ]),
            width: 100,
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(2),
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(18),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                border: Border.all(color: Colors.white),
              ),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Text(
                    "Today",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10, color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    "99 Pkr",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10, color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 128, 128, 1),
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(
                      0.5,
                    ),
                    spreadRadius: 5,
                    blurRadius: 7,
                    offset: Offset(0, 2),
                  ),
                ]),
            width: 100,
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(1),
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(18),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                border: Border.all(color: Colors.white),
              ),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Text(
                    "7 Days",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10, color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    "1560 Pkr",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10, color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Color.fromRGBO(128, 128, 0, 1),
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(
                      0.5,
                    ),
                    spreadRadius: 5,
                    blurRadius: 7,
                    offset: Offset(0, 2),
                  ),
                ]),
            width: 100,
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(1),
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(18),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                border: Border.all(color: Colors.white),
              ),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Text(
                    "30 Days",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10, color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    "25467 Pkr",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10, color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Dashboard(),
    );
  }
}

class ExpenceDisplayPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(body: Center(child: Text("ExpenceDisplayPage")));
  }
}
```